# Espèce du mot "quelque"

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, adverbes

> Ce film, quelque intéressant qu'il soit, est trop long.

Est-ce que quelque est un adverbe ou un adjectif dans ce contexte ? Comment peut-on savoir ça ici ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un principe de raisonnement infaillible consiste à partir de ce que l'on sait : des deux mots, « quelque » et « intéressant », « intéressant » est un adjectif ; comme la succession de deux adjectifs n'est pas une possibilité en tant qu'attributs sans une virgule de séparation¹, « quelque » ne peut pas être un adjectif et c'est donc un adverbe.

Cet usage est  assez rare ; il est attesté au TLFi comme étant littéraire ;

> II. Quelque ... que, loc. exprimant la concession ou l'opposition, suivie du subj.
> B. Littér., inv. au plur. [Portant sur un adj., la sub. comportant un verbe attributif] Synon. pour* ... que (lang. soutenue), aussi ... que (v. aussi1), si ... que (v. si1), quoique, bien que (v. bien1).
>
> - Ce fait est vrai, quelque extraordinaire qu'il puisse paraître[…]
> - Quelque méritantes que puissent être, au point de vue du patriotisme, les œuvres dont je viens de passer la revue, elles ne témoignent cependant d'aucun effort artistique sérieux...

¹<sub>Ce principe n'est pas parfaitement exact ; il y a au moins l'exception de certain adjectifs de couleur composés : blanc laiteux, vert clair, marron foncé …([ref](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/synonyme/marron_clair.php)). Dans ces combinaisons qui ne constituent qu'un seul adjectif, les deux mots sont des adjectifs ([ref](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frcouleur.php)).</sub>

Comment: Comment la succession de deux adjectifs n'est pas une possibilité sans une virgule de séparation ? Par exemple on peut dire *c'est une jolie petite maison*, pas de virgule, non ?

Comment: @lmc Bien trouvé !  Mon assertion n'est pas tout à fait bonne ; il faudrait stipuler "dans ces cas où l'adjectif ne figure pas en tant qu'épithète" ; je crois cependant qu'avec cette réserve, cela est vrai.

Comment: ...en tant qu'épithète du sujet, parce que _jolie_ et _petite_ sont des épithètes emboîtées de _maison_, le noyau. De plus il n'y a pas que la virgule puisque la coordination est aussi possible, de sorte qu'en employant cette « logique » tu te trouves à affirmer quelque chose d'incomplet et inexact à la fois pour un sujet qui n'avait aucun lien avec la question. Le genre de déduction dont tu parles n'est pas « infaillible » et ce n'est pas la voie à suivre à mon avis pour déterminer la nature de _quelque... que_, il faut simplement identifier la locution et non procéder par élimination.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Lorsque l'on n'est pas très avancé dans la pratique de déterminer la nature grammaticale des mots, avant de pouvoir faire la connexion entre « quelque » et « que » on a besoin d'avoir une idée de la nature de « quelque » et comme c'est en cherchant à adverbe dans le dictionnaire que l'on arrive à « quelque  … que », et pas à partir de l'adjectif, il importe bien d'abord de reconnaitre « quelque » comme étant un adverbe. Les épithètes sont exclus du principe (seulement vrai pour les adjectif attributs et les adjectifs mis en apposition, pris en compte par une modification).

Comment: @Survenant9r7 C'est à peine une méthode, plutôt un fait de la syntaxe qui peut occasionnellement servir (comme dans le présent cas) et de plus, si insignifiant qu'il paraisse, intéressant à connaitre: c'est une caractéristique du noyau du syntagme adjectival non épithète. Je ne crois pas faire référence à une façon de procéder rigoureuse qui passerait au peigne fin le contexte grammatical pour n'exclure aucune possibilité, ni devoir le faire; c'est certainement possible et un jour prochain des machines feront  ça de façon efficace;  il n'est question que de fournir une indication utile.